# How to Rotate, Scale, and Translate Bitmap on Canvas in OnTounchEvent

Tags: android, canvas

I am new to Android and currently working one project. 
I have rectangle image and to overlap small circle bitmap, in the right-bottom corner of the rectangle image.My Question is how to achieve for Rotate, Scale and Translate for single touch(Down, move, up) on the circle at the every time. please any one post code/idea here. Thanks for Advance help.

Comment: View animations in android can be useful to you . Here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: I already referred that. i don't need animation but the combination of three operation how i do? plz any idea

Comment: androidhive.info , you can find your solution there

Comment: Try to use AnimatorSet - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html . You can play the multiple animations together by putting them in a set.

Comment: how to rotate rect in android. i drawRect with bitmap, try to rotate that rect. how is it possible? without using matrix and canvas rotate. please any one post your idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to these links for rotating image using angle:

- http://www.evancharlton.com/thoughts/android-rotating-touch-events
- http://www.f15ijp.com/2012/05/android-rotate-a-bitmap/
- http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

Answer (score -1):

refer this link,this link having for rotate and scale functionality for 2 different action u have combine it.

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/rotate-bitmap-image-using-matrix.html